# Ever use RabbitMQ and Node.js for long running process?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I'm trying to understand the best way to handle a long running task in Node.js. Apparently doing a long running process in Node.js is not a good idea because the single threaded nature of node.

I'm a big fan of RabbitMQ so I was thinking of having two node servers with rabbit in between:

```
Node.js Web Server <--> RabbitMQ <--> Node.js Backend Worker
```

The idea of course is to not slow down the web server ever. I would normally replace the backend server with Java but I'm trying to keep it all JS.

I'm not a Node programmer so I'm not sure if this is a good idea or even possible? Has anyone tried something like this?

Comment: I ended up just making the backend worker Java but still have node in the front and rabbit in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you mean by "long running process" -- to block Node.JS, you'd have to do lots of computation all at once. Doing I/O (roughly, invoking something that takes a callback argument) will yield to the event loop.

There are arguably few things one would do in a web site that don't involve mostly I/O. For example, talking to a database -- I/O. Reading a template from the filesystem -- I/O. (Running a template with data from the database -- ok, not I/O. Probably not very expensive, either.)

If you have just two Node.JS processes as in your diagram, the response to each client is still going to take as long as it would anyway (I/O time plus computation time). However, you may get better throughput, as you wouldn't be serialising incoming requests. On the other hand the requests may just back up in RabbitMQ, turning your higher throughput into higher latency.

You also then have the opportunity to run /more/ than one backend worker, to get through requests faster.  Doing the work in just the web server, but running a bunch of web server processes and load-balancing across those with say, nginx, would have a similar effect.

Comment: When I mean long running I mean batch importing or processing that would take at least a couple minutes to a couple hours. These are not processes' necessarily kicked off by a normal user request. I think Java is a better option cause: I know it really well :), Hadoop, and while Java sucks the JVM is kind of good at this stuff. I like RabbitMQ in place because I can switch it back to NodeJS later when I feel more comfortable.